# BT socket Device over Structured Cabling

Tags: cable, infrastructure

Essentially I have a Credit Card machine which is connected to a phone line via standard BT Socket.

So basically, the port of the wall has a balun plugged in which takes the RJ45 outlet on the wall to BT, so I can plug the device in. This works fine, however I need the machine to be on the other side of the room so want to route it through my patch panel (strucutered cabling).

How can this be done?

So `Device` --> ? --> RJ45 port --> Patch Panel --> ? --> Balun out wall outlet

Where ? is to be filled in!

Comment: Is your PSTN line currently connected into your structured wiring, eg, do you need to connect the BT socket on the wall into your infrastructure or is that already in place?

Comment: It's an independent PSTN line for a credit card machine, it won't be in use for anything else.

Comment: The important part of this isn't the credit card machine, it's the PSTN - once you get that onto your structured wiring it should be plain sailing. Is the PSTN currently connected to your structured wiring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this. What you need is one of these:

http://www.cables2u.co.uk/rj45-network-pabx-phone-adapter-p-903.html?gclid=CLeClMTTiLgCFQbJtAodun8Acw

Thw differance between MASTER and Slave  is that master shoukd be used on devices that ring using the pstn (example a very old phone that draws power from pstn)

A slave should be used for digial devices. The only differance is there is a capicter in the master to enable no influx in voltage.